# Convert function Remove and Replace on .Net to PHP

Tags: php, .net, substring, substr

Let me show my decompiler result with [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) for programming Visual C# .NET 
And at this case, honestly I'm still newbie of programming languange. This is the snip of decompiling coding of  Visual C# .NET :

```
private string Oye = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
```

and these are the the other Class from Visual C# .NET code listings below :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string text = this.Oye.Substring(6, 1);
            text += this.Oye.Substring(0, 1);
            text += this.Oye.Substring(13, 1);
            text += this.Oye.Substring(19, 1);
            text += this.Oye.Substring(4, 1);
            text += text.Substring(2, 1);
            text += text.Substring(0, 1);
            text += this.Oye.Substring(26, 5);
            text = text.Remove(10, 1);
            text = text.Replace(text.Substring(9, 1), text.Substring(7, 1));
            text = text.Replace(text.Substring(7, 1), this.Oye.Substring(28, 1));
            text = text.Replace(text.Substring(8, 2), this.Oye.Substring(26, 2));
            MD5 mD = MD5.Create();
            byte[] array = mD.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                stringBuilder.Append(array[i].ToString("x2"));
            }
            if (this.textBox1.Text == text)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(stringBuilder.ToString(), "Success");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Repeat Again");
            }
        }
```

So far, I'm trying for find the result of **$text** on PHP, these are my PHP codes for converting .Net to PHP :

```
<?php

    $Oye = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    $text = substr($Oye, 6, 1);
    $text += substr($Oye, 0, 1);
    $text += substr($Oye, 13, 1);
    $text += substr($Oye, 4, 1);
    $text += substr($text, 2, 1);
    $text += substr($text, 0, 1);
    $text += substr($Oye, 26, 5);
    /* I'm confused for convert Visual C# .NET codes to PHP for "Remove" and "Replace" according from snip code Visual C# .NET above */

    echo $text;
?>
```

Let me know how to convert `text = text.Remove(10, 1);`
and `text = text.Replace(text.Substring(9, 1), text.Substring(7, 1));`(C #.NET programming) to PHP. I have tried learning some references about substr_replace and str_replace on PHP but I'm confused and don't understand how to convert the snip codes of C# .Net above to the PHP programming code.

Please, anybody gives me solution or example how to convert those codes to PHP? Are my some PHP codes true to convert its from .NET?

Thank you very much for attention and for answer of my problem.

sincerely, 
Ratu Lebah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated my PHP from .NET based on [Mark M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2253331/mark-m) suggestion. 
So these are my PHP listing codes :

```
<?php

    $Oye = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    $text = substr($Oye, 6, 1);
    $text += substr($Oye, 0, 1);
    $text += substr($Oye, 13, 1);
    $text += substr($Oye, 19, 1);
    $text += substr($Oye, 4, 1);
    $text += substr($text, 2, 1);
    $text += substr($text, 0, 1);
    $text += substr($Oye, 26, 5);

    /* I Follow some suggestion from Mark for this code bellow : */
    $text = substr_replace($text, '', 10, 1);

    /* I Follow some suggestion from Mark too */
    $text = str_replace(substr($text, 9, 1), substr($text, 7, 1), $text);
    $text = str_replace(substr($text, 7, 1), substr($Oye, 28, 1), $text);
    $text = str_replace(substr($text, 8, 2), substr($Oye, 26, 2), $text);

    echo $text;
?>
```

and the result from my web browser is : **`1234`**

I'm so thanks and really appreciated your helping for my case above but if I rewrite .Net (decompiling code above) to C# and I got the different answer.

These are my C# listing codes bellow:

```
using System.IO;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
     string str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
     var text = str.Substring(6, 1);
     text += str.Substring(0, 1);

     text += str.Substring(13, 1);
     text += str.Substring(19, 1);
     text += str.Substring(4, 1);

     text += text.Substring(2, 1);
     text += text.Substring(0, 1);

     text += str.Substring(26, 5);

     text = text.Remove(10, 1);
     text = text.Replace(text.Substring(9, 1), text.Substring(7, 1));

     text = text.Replace(text.Substring(7, 1), str.Substring(28, 1));
     text = text.Replace(text.Substring(8, 2), str.Substring(26, 2));  

     Console.WriteLine(text);
    }
}
```

and the result from **text** variable is **`ganteng2014`**

Do you have any suggestions or recommendation? or might you give me some diretions for re-update PHP codes? Or Are my C# codes wrong? Because the result from PHP and C# I made was different (`1234` *[result on PHP]* and `ganteng2014`*[result on C#]*)

Answer (score 1):

PHP equivalent for `text = text.Remove(10, 1);`

```
$text = substr_replace($text, '', 10, 1);
```

PHP equivalent for `text = text.Replace(text.Substring(9, 1), text.Substring(7, 1));`

```
$text = str_replace(substr($text, 9, 1), substr($text, 7, 1), $text);
```

---

[See demo](http://codepad.org/798J6kaL)

*References:*
*[**substr_replace()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php), [**str_replace()**](http://php.net/str_replace), [**substr()**](http://php.net/substr)*